# How to mock loadable.lib to make the library be loaded synchronously in some unit tests?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, webpack, razzle

We now use lazy-loading through `loadable.lib` for about 20 new files which used to load the npm module `react-toastify` synchronously. The changes are waiting in a draft PR but it seems that the unit tests are broken because they do not wait for the `loadable.lib`-passed module to be loaded.

## Expected results

Be able to mock `loadable.lib` so that it works exactly like before but loads the given library synchronously and in the unit test this is seen as the children of `loadable.lib` resulted Component have access to that library and a first render does this successfully.

## Actual results

The old snapshot (full of tags and nested things and props) and the new one (`null`) are not matching. These do not work:

```js
// TODO: not working because loadable is used in many places
// and children are not always enough to render to avoid crashes,
// and even just with children there can be crashes
jest.mock('@loadable/component', (loadfn) => ({
  lib: jest.fn(() => {
    return { toast: {} };
  }),
}));
```

If it is possible to mock the `loadable.lib` function to render its children instead of wait for some library to be loaded, I don't know how I can fill the undefined variables that the code uses because I have loadables that use loadables that use loadables and so on.

I've read that there are some WebPack hints such as `webpackPrefetch` and `webpackPreload` but I am not sure if it is a good road to go.

## Relevant links on what I have tried

1. The code I am working on (and there are 19 other files like this one): https://github.com/silviubogan/volto/blob/1d015c145e562565ecfa058629ae3d7a9f3e39e4/src/components/manage/Actions/Actions.jsx (I am currently working on loading `react-toastify` through `loadable.lib` always.)
2. https://medium.com/pixel-and-ink/testing-loadable-components-with-jest-97bfeaa6da0b - I tried to do a similar thing like the code in that article but it is not working:

```js
jest.mock('@loadable/component', async (loadfn) => {
   const val = await loadfn();
   return {
     lib: () => val,
   };
});
```

## A little bit of code

Taken from [the link above](https://github.com/silviubogan/volto/blob/1d015c145e562565ecfa058629ae3d7a9f3e39e4/src/components/manage/Actions/Actions.jsx), this is how I currently use react-toastify (named `LoadableToast`):

```
/**
 * Render method.
 * @method render
 * @returns {string} Markup for the component.
 */
render() {
  return (
    <LoadableToast>
      {({ default: toast }) => {
        this.toast = toast;

        return (
          <Dropdown
            item
            id="toolbar-actions"
```

## Conclusion

To put it in other words, how can I mock a dynamic import? How can I make jest go over lazy loading and provide a value instead of making the test wait to receive a value?

Thank you!

## Update 1

With the following new code, still not working:

```
jest.mock('@loadable/component', (load) => {
  return {
    lib: () => {
      let Component;
      const loadPromise = load().then((val) => (Component = val.default));
      const Loadable = (props) => {
        if (!Component) {
          throw new Error(
            'Bundle split module not loaded yet, ensure you beforeAll(() => MyLazyComponent.load()) in your test, import statement: ' +
              load.toString(),
          );
        }
        return <Component {...props} />;
      };
      Loadable.load = () => loadPromise;
      return Loadable;
    },
  };
});
```

Answer (score 4):

A better solution is to mock the Loadable components module. We can do this simply by using Jest mock capabilities (https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules) and Loadable itself in the following way:

1. Create a @loadable directory inside the **mocks** folder at the root level of your project (**mocks** should be at the same level of node_modules).
2. Inside the @loadable folder, create a component.js file. In this file we will mock the loadable function by writing the code below:

```
export default function (load) {
  return load.requireSync();
}
```

That's it, now you should be able to run your unit tests as normal.

Comment: Tweaked this slightly and it worked for us:

return load.requireSync()?.default;

Answer (score 2):

We did it by

```js
jest.mock('@loadable/component', () => ({
    lib: () => {
        const MegadraftEditor = () => {} // Name of your import
        return ({ children }) => children({ default: { MegadraftEditor } })
    },
}))
```

In case there is only one default export it could also be

```js
jest.mock('@loadable/component', () => ({
lib: () => {
    const HotTable = () => {} // Name of your import
    return ({ children }) => children({ default: HotTable })
},
}))
```

Then in the test you just need to dive() and use childAt() until you have the correct location of the component you want to lazy-load. Note that this will then not have any of your wrappers around the lazy-loaded component in the snapshot.

```js
it('renders correct', () => {
    const component = shallow(
        <View
            data={}
        />
    )
        .dive()
        .childAt(0)
        .dive()

    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```